# How could I wrap a string around each file, plus include the file name, with make?

Tags: makefile

I'm not too familiar with makefiles, and the manual confuses me to no end. I've got a situation where I need to wrap text around each file in a directory, and put the filename into the file as well.

Basically I'm starting with this:

```
file1.exp
file2.exp
...
```

And need to transform each file in the directory like this:

```
"string1" [fileX's filename] "string2" [fileX's contents] "string3" > fileX.tmp
```

How can this be done with a makefile? Or should I take another route, complicating my application with another build method?

On a side note, if you can recommend any make tutorials that are less likely to just leave me confused, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
all: fileX.tmp fileY.tmp

%.tmp : %
        echo "string1 $< string2 `cat $<` string3" > $@
```

This will fail if your files have lots of content: it's not really clear from your questions what the parameters and requirements.  Does this all have to appear on the same line?  Multiple lines?  I just implemented exactly what you asked for above.

Comment: Rather than try to pack this into a single action, why not just use multiple actions in the recipe? e.g. `%.tmp: %.exp ... echo "string1" > $@; echo $< >> $@; echo "string2" >> $@; cat $< >> $@; echo "string3" >> $@;` (Insert -n where appropriate).

Comment: Well, that's why I said that the requirements were not well-defined.  The difference between my answer and yours is that yours will add newlines after each item "string1", "$<", etc. and mine won't.  All we have to go by is the example above, where there are no newlines, so that's how I implemented my example.

Comment: Good point. Also, your solution has the advantage that it only spawns 2-3 additional processes (sh, echo is probably a shell builtin, and cat), instead of 2-10 (depending on newline escaping). However, most implementations of echo have a switch to suppress the newline, and not doing command expansion on the contents of `$<` protects against the command line being too long.